# How to reinstall PHP cURL on Xampp Windows 10?

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I am currently having a problem where it looks like PHP cURL 7.76.1 is not working with PHP 8.0.8. i already checked my php.ini file and the extension has been enabled, also when checking phpinfo.php i see a section called curl which means it recognizes the extension. I would like to know if it is necessary to reinstall the extension or maybe upgrade to a newer version if available and how i need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php8.0 should have php8.0-*extension-name* installed.

```sh
sudo apt install php8.0-extension_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when i try to execute the command i get the following error: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. this is because i am using windows 10 and windows doesn't know what sudo is

Comment: Have you tried all traces of PHP and Xampp and re-installing Xampp 8.0.9? Usually it has all basic extensions

Comment: Yes! i reinstalled Xampp, but this didn't help

Comment: Can you tell how you determined that cUrl is not working?

Comment: The live version of the website recently got upgraded to the latest php version, so my local version had to upgrade aswell. we encountered an error and this one has been fixed after a while. the person who fixed this one said it had something to do with the php cURL package not working after the upgrade. the problem is that the error still exist on my local version

Comment: Check openssl version too

Comment: i have OpenSSL version 1.1.1K